# Best way to know if http request is GET or POST with DPKT?

Tags: python, http

I'm using the function dpkt.http.Request(), but sometimes the http flow is not a request.
Is there a quick way in python or dpkt to know if my request is GET or POST?

Comment: You could try Fiddler: http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/

Answer (score 1):

Try parsing it as a HTTP request and catch `dpkt.UnpackError` so your program doesn't die if it's not a HTTP request.

If no exception was thrown, you can use `.method` of the `Request` object to get the method that was used.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> import dpkt
>>> r = dpkt.Request('GET / HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n')
```

[Finding the HTTP verb is easy:](http://code.google.com/p/dpkt/source/browse/trunk/dpkt/http.py)

```
>>> r.method
"GET"
```

If there is difficulty parsing the HTTP request data, then it is impossible to get the original source data back because of how the [`dpkt.Request.unpack`](http://code.google.com/p/dpkt/source/browse/trunk/dpkt/http.py#124) method handles exceptions.

As a workaround something like this may be handy:

```
>>> data = 'GET / HTT' #malformed request
>>> try:
...     r = dpkt.Request(data)
... except dpkt.UnpackError:
...     print data.split()[0]
...
'GET'
```

Comment: That is incorrect, because dpkt not always can parse the Request.

Comment: Have expanded the answer to deal with messy requests.

Comment: If this solved your problem, please accept the answer by clicking on the tick.